# Downloading a nested collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

How do I get an object from context with a nested collection as an id list?

I want to get a Flat object containing a list of user IDs.

```
public IEnumerable<Flat> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Flats
        .Include(flat => flat.Users.Select(x => x.Id));
}
```

The error returned:

`The property expression 'flat => {from User x in flat.Users select [x].Id}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.`

Comment: Is this EntityFramework?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. You want all `Flats` objects also get list of IDs from users associated with each flat?

Answer (score 5):

This should be one way to do it:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Flats
        .Include(flat => flat.Users)
        .Select(flat => new { Flat = flat, UserIds = flat.Users.Select(u => u.Id) });
}
```

Although you probably want to define a new type to return.